# How to scrape information based on product selection(ex. Size, Color, Pack)?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, scrapy, selection

I successfully crawled over 1600 pages last week. But was informed that a good portion of the data returned was incorrect as to what was pulled.(i.e. price) by that i mean that if the item being crawled had the option to make selection (size, color, qty/pack) in order to see the price, how would i be able to gather the correct price per selection? Seems that my logic was pulling the first price it found.

I was trying in early attempts to just parse every combination available within the page code, but that was always failing to return accurately, that i moved to pulling just 1 price, but seems that most of the test pages I used were not option specific pricing, so i overlooked a good portion of URL's that were not similar in layout and functionality. Currently the only thing that works is the code i have which can be found here..

```
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55925202/why-does-this-code-generate-multiple-files-i-want-1-file-with-all-entries-in-it/55925220#55925220
```

This works great and as expected for any item page we crawl that doesn't have any selection to be made..

```
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55925202/why-does-this-code-generate-multiple-files-i-want-1-file-with-all-entries-in-it/55925220#55925220
```

Entire code is already posted here with the final version that is working.

I dont need full examples, i just need some guidance on what to focus on within the code in order to automatically make product selections in order to get the correct price, selection combo

Here is an example page that was one that didn't pull the correct price:
    https://www.dickssportinggoods.com/p/berkley-vanish-fluorocarbon-fishing-line-15bkyuvnsh25010clfli/15bkyuvnsh25010clfli

The price changes when you start to make selections, if you choose "6" pound and "2000 yds" the price will change to $75.99, then if you change it to "250 yds" then the price changes to $12.99

Since we will from time to time have a need to pull a specific pound and length, what do i need to focus on in order to systemically pull the correct price for the needed selections?

Is there a way to just pull all the combinations per page while there so that we aren't hitting the same page over and over?

I've looked at some links here and other sites that seem to deal with this, but little lost if they are even the same thing i'm trying to accomplish.

Just looking for some guidance on where to start or what to try..

Comment: I can see only `"We're sorry to say that due to the General Data Protection Regulation, visitors from your location are unable to browse our web store."`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While using scrapy, if you want all combinations you will need to make sure to include all conditions inside of your script, which as you know is completely unreasonable.

I would use two different parsers, scrapy for general scraping and selenium for more specific scraping. Using selenium, you can input specific combinations in your script and parse prices on the page like so:

```
import requests
import urllib3
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import os
import traceback
import io
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC


chrome_options = Options()
#chrome_options.add_argument('--headless')
#chrome_options.add_argument('--hide-scrollbars')
#chrome_options.add_argument('--disable-gpu')
#chrome_options.add_argument("--log-level=3")  # fatal

url = 'https://www.dickssportinggoods.com/p/berkley-vanish-fluorocarbon-fishing-line-15bkyuvnsh25010clfli/15bkyuvnsh25010clfli'

browser = webdriver.Chrome(
    executable_path=r'C:\Users\edekio\Documents\chromedriver.exe', chrome_options=chrome_options)
browser.get(url)

pounds = browser.find_element_by_link_text('14').click()

length = browser.find_element_by_link_text('250 yds').click()

price = WebDriverWait(browser, 60).until(
    EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "ProductInfoPrice_740978")))

price_text = price.get_attribute('value')
print(price_text)
```

Output:

```
14.99
```

As you can see we can pass in specific values into the boxes using selenium, thus getting the exact price you want. However the above script is not all inclusive, but it should be a good starting point.